# UITapGesture not working on dynamically created UIViews

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitapgesturerecognizer

I am making dynamic `UIViews` through code and trying to add `UITapGestureRecogniser` on them. But for some reason, they are not responding. Here is the code :

```
-(void)createRandomBlock{
    UIView * block = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake([self getRandomPosition], 0-_heightOfBlock, _widthOfBlock, _heightOfBlock)];
    block.backgroundColor = [self randomColor];
    block.userInteractionEnabled=YES;

    UITapGestureRecognizer * tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(blockTapped:)];
    tapGesture.delegate = self;
    tapGesture.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
    tapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired=1;
    [block addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];

    [self.view addSubview:block];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:_durationOfAnimation delay:0.0 options:options animations:^{
        [block setFrame:CGRectMake(block.frame.origin.x, ScreenHeight, block.bounds.size.width, block.bounds.size.height)];
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        [block removeFromSuperview];
    }];
}

-(void)blockTapped:(UITapGestureRecognizer*)gesture{
    NSLog(@"I am being called?");
    UIView * block = (UIView*)[gesture view];
    [block removeFromSuperview];
}
```

Can someone please help?

Thanks

Comment: is the createRandomBlock called once?

Comment: presumably you can see the view on screen? what other gestures are on the view and the superview?

Comment: createRandomBlock is being called using a timer with delay of 3 seconds. 
also, I am using uiviewanimate to animate the view.

Comment: and yes I can see the UIView there. I can also see it being animated.

Comment: Code updated. I think my UIViewAnimate is causing the issue.

Comment: From the animation completion code, you are removing these views. So exactly when you are trying to tap them? You can't do that in the middle of animation and once animation finished you don't have the view to tap to!!!

Comment: I need the user to tap them during the animation to remove them from the frame.

Comment: I can see them being animated from top to bottom of the screen. how can I implement this feature that when you tap, it gets removed from the superview. Or it gets removed when the animation ends.

Comment: what is your screen height default device height ??

Comment: #define ScreenHeight [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried with same code, it worked for me. **Only change being, I didn't set the delegate for the tapGesture**.

```
-(void)createRandomBlock{
    UIView * block = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:randomPosition];
    block.backgroundColor = [self randomColor];
    block.userInteractionEnabled=YES;

    UITapGestureRecognizer * tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(blockTapped:)];
    tapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired=1;
    [block addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];

    [self.view addSubview:block];
}

-(void)blockTapped:(UITapGestureRecognizer*)gesture{
    NSLog(@"I am being called?");
    UIView * block = (UIView*)[gesture view];
    [block removeFromSuperview];
}
```

I guess because of adding delegate, it overrides the selector which you have specified and calls the delegate methods instead.

Comment: Can you please try the updated code. I think my UIViewAnimate is causing the issue.

Comment: @WarisAli: Can you tell properly what you are trying to do in the animation. By looking at the code, it seems to me that you are creating the view then animating the view after that on completion, removing it. When do you want to call the tapgesture selector. Can you please be more clear.

Comment: @WarisAli : This might help : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4311645/uiview-touchesbegan-doesnt-respond-during-animation/4432546#4432546

Answer (score 1):

You can little mistake on frame set. please change frame set & you can solve your problem.

```
-(void)createRandomBlock{
    int x_coord = arc4random() % 200; //Random number from 0-320  // set random x position 
    int y_coord = arc4random() % 481; //Random number from 0-480  // set random y position

    UIView * block = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x_coord, y_coord, 100, 100)]; // for testing set width & height 100 * 100
    block.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor]; // for fix color you can use your change color function
    block.userInteractionEnabled=YES;

    UITapGestureRecognizer * tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(blockTapped:)];
    tapGesture.delegate = self;
    tapGesture.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
    tapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired=1;
    [block addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];

    [self.view addSubview:block];

[UIView animateKeyframesWithDuration:1.0 delay:0.0 options:UIViewKeyframeAnimationOptionCalculationModeLinear animations:^{
        [block setFrame:CGRectMake(block.frame.origin.x, 0, block.bounds.size.width, block.bounds.size.height)];
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
//        [block removeFromSuperview];
    }];
}

-(void)blockTapped:(UITapGestureRecognizer*)gesture{
    NSLog(@"I am being called?");
    UIView * block = (UIView*)[gesture view];
    [block removeFromSuperview];
}
```

Comment: there is no problem with the frame of the uiview. I can see the uiview on my main view. The x,y,width and height of the block is being adjusted in the other code.

Comment: what is your screen height default device height ??  please check my code

Comment: #define ScreenHeight [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height

Comment: you can set Y = ScreenHeight, so you can't see the view controller. right now in my code you see the custom view controller come to bottom to top.

Answer (score 1):

If your top view's user interactions are disabled, your gestures will not recognize interactions on your subviews as well. Try to add the fallowing line somewhere before calling createRandomBlock message.

`self.view.userInteractionEnabled = YES;`

Comment: Yes. Top view interaction is enabled. No issues there.

Comment: Sure. Here are the needed files. 
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/puwc6gv09tm0kb4/AAAMEI6mUfXhWplVmOXsBazDa?dl=0

Comment: Well. your gestures didn't work because UIView's animation actually setting the frame of the views immediately when it has being called. What you see are actually the presentation layers of the views, not views themselves.

Comment: Yes. I did some research and I found that. 
So moving forward people are suggesting that adding UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction will solve the problem but apparently it is not doing anything :(
Any suggestions please?

Comment: The only solution i know is to remove presentation layer's animation.

Comment: Add tap gesture to your top view and add the fallowing code to it's selector.
`CALayer *touchedLayer = [self.view.layer.presentationLayer hitTest:[tap locationInView:self.view]];
    [touchedLayer removeAllAnimations];`

Comment: Hmmm. Thankyou but that wont solve my problem of detecting and delteting that particular UIView. So what I am doing is adding the gesture recognizer to the uiviewcontrollers uiview and using hittest to check which of the block is being tapped. I will traverse through all of the view currently on the screen. Thanks for your help!

Comment: It actually do what you want. When you calling removeAllAnimations method on presentation layer instance it will immediately call [UIView animateWithDuration:....] method's completion block, probably with NO value of the finished argument.

Comment: Well yes that is the problem my friend. When should I call removeAllAnimation function when the tap gesture is not working in first place :)

Answer (score 1):

I dont know what your [self getRandomPosition] and  _widthOfBlock etc have value otherwise below code works fine in my demo.

```
 -(void)createRandomBlock{

UIView * block = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 200)];
block.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
block.userInteractionEnabled=YES;

UITapGestureRecognizer * tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(blockTapped:)];
tapGesture.delegate = self;
tapGesture.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
tapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired=1;
[block addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];

[self.view addSubview:block];
}

-(void)blockTapped:(UITapGestureRecognizer*)gesture{
NSLog(@"I am being called?");
UIView * block = (UIView*)[gesture view];
[block removeFromSuperview];
}
```

**Update :**

You should use `touchesBegan` to recognize touch, here is the working code,

```
-(void)createRandomBlock{

UIView * block = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 200)];
block.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
block.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
block.tag = 100;
self.view.userInteractionEnabled =YES;

UITapGestureRecognizer * tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(blockTapped:)];
//  tapGesture.delegate = self;
// tapGesture.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
tapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired=1;


[block addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];
[self.view addSubview:block];




 [UIView animateWithDuration:5.0 delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction animations:^{
    [block setFrame:CGRectMake(block.frame.origin.x, self.view.frame.size.height-200, block.bounds.size.width, block.bounds.size.height)];


} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    [block removeFromSuperview];
}];


}

-(void)blockTapped:(UITapGestureRecognizer*)gesture{

NSLog(@"I am being called?");
UIView * block = (UIView*)[gesture view];
[block removeFromSuperview];
}


- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInView:self.view];
UIView *tempView = [self.view viewWithTag:100];

if ([tempView.layer.presentationLayer hitTest:touchLocation]) {

    NSLog(@"call");
    [tempView removeFromSuperview];
}


}
```

Comment: please ignore the random functions and variables that I am using. They are working fine.

Comment: Check my updated answer it's works as your requirement. :)

Answer (score 0):

You are removing the view in completion block, which means after animation is completed your view will be removed. Remove the below line from completion block.

```
[block removeFromSuperview];
```

You should not be doing that. Your view itself is removed how Tap Gesture will work.

Comment: The view is removed after it gets out of the screen.

Comment: I am tapping it during the animation.

Comment: I have tried taking that line out. Didnt do anything. Still the gesture is not working

Comment: [block setFrame:CGRectMake(block.frame.origin.x, ScreenHeight, block.bounds.size.width, block.bounds.size.height)]; ScreenHeight is already height of screen and  y origin co-ordinate is ScreenHeight which means it will start from below the screen. Make Y-Axis to something to show in the display view.